# Why does the bottom for loop does not include last element?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, rotation

Problem: Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Example: Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

I tried doing this:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        x = nums
        for i in range(0, k):
            temp = []
            temp += [x.pop()]
            for i in  range(0, len(x)):
                temp += [x[i]]
            x = temp
     
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            nums[i] = x[i]
```

I only get the output of [5,6,7,1,2,3] and I am not sure why the last element i.e. 4 is chopped off even though I see it when I tried printing x.

Credit: This a leetcode question

Answer (score 0):

The size of your nums array is shrinking above. It shrink from 7 to 6 , it is not my
dominant language so I'm having trouble understanding the syntax and hence I can't catch the bug. So it is going one less from the original x array's size.

So it never reaches the the 4 .

One work around I can think of is adding the last element after :

```
for i in range(0, len(nums)):
nums[i] = x[i]

nums.append(x[len(x)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to make a copy of your nums by x = nums, but that is not how python works (other languages might differ). Anything you apply on x, applies to nums as well. Since you are using x.pop(), the nums array also shrinks irreversibly. In order to make a copy of the nums, you can use nums[:]. I changed your code and it works now. (ran it on leetcode as well)

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        x = nums[:]
        for i in range(0, k):
            temp = []
            temp += [x.pop()]
            for i in  range(0, len(x)):
                temp += [x[i]]
            x = temp
     
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            nums[i] = x[i]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering how can we work on overcoming time exceed error.

Comment: You are welcome! you need to optimize the time complexity of your algorithm for instance you currently have two nested for loops which are causing your time complexity to increase. See whether you can eliminate one of the nested loops.